# Problema no build android do ionic "Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable"

Tags: android, apache-cordova, ionic

Tentei diversas respostas para o erro abaixo encontradas aqui mesmo no SO mas nenhuma resolveu o problema. Ao executar o comando `sudo ionic build android` é retornada a seguinte mensagem

```
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Detected 'android' command at /opt/android-studio/bin but no 'tools' directory found near.
Try reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

As variáveis de ambiente ANDROID_HOME e PATH aparentam estar configuradas corretamente

```
leonardo@antunesleo:~/projects/devcoffee/coffee-force$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/leonardo/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/leonardo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools

leonardo@antunesleo:~/projects/devcoffee/coffee-force$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/leonardo/Android/Sdk
```

O meu Sdk se encontra no diretório exibido abaixo.

```
/home/leonardo/Android/Sdk
```

o diretório tools e platform-tools está dentro do Sdk, como o esperado.

```
leonardo@antunesleo:~/Android/Sdk$ ls
add-ons  build-tools  extras  licenses  Link para SDK Readme.txt  platforms  platform-tools  SDK Readme.txt  sources  tools
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no "sudo" antes da execução do comando `ionic build`. Aparentemente no ubuntu o sudo usa caminhos diferentes. Estava utilizando o sudo pois sem ele era informado que não tinha permissão para executa o comando. Dei permissão total na pros arquivos/repositório do projeto e executei o `ionic build` sem o sudo na frente, resolveu o problema!

Answer (score 1):

Será que não é problema de permissão no diretório do Android?

Antes de checar as permissões, tente atribuir separadamente cada variável para facilitar:

No meu caso uso MAC e faço dessa forma e nunca tive problemas (os diretórios podem variar, é claro) :

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk"
export ANDROID_TOOLS="/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/"
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_TOOLS:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é devido as permissões root do linux , pode-se usar o comando sudo chown -R usuario  pasta do projeto